# Retrieve Firebase Key

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

how can I get the Firebase key of a collection of a `ViewHolder` at `RecyclerViewAdapter` of the `holder` that has been clicked?
I need to send the key to other activity using intent and retrieve it on the other activity to use the same data as the `ViewHolder` that has been clicked.

My code -

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final PostsAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

final String header_data = list_post.get(position).getHeader();
holder.setHeaderText(header_data);

final String desc_data = list_post.get(position).getDesc1();
holder.setDescText(desc_data);

final String date_data = list_post.get(position).getDate1();
holder.setDateText(date_data);

final String image_data = list_post.get(position).getImage_url();
holder.setIntroIMG(image_data);


holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent goToFullPost = new Intent(context, FullPostActivity.class);
        goToFullPost.putExtra("header", header_data);
        goToFullPost.putExtra("desc1", desc_data);
        goToFullPost.putExtra("date1", date_data);
        goToFullPost.putExtra("image_url", image_data);
        context.startActivity(goToFullPost);

     }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should still have access to `position` in your `onClick`. In that case, you can get the reference:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    String key = adapter.getRef(position).getKey();

    Intent goToFullPost = new Intent(context, FullPostActivity.class);
    goToFullPost.putExtra("header", header_data);
    goToFullPost.putExtra("desc1", desc_data);
    goToFullPost.putExtra("date1", date_data);
    goToFullPost.putExtra("image_url", image_data);
    context.startActivity(goToFullPost);

 }
```

Comment: What do I type instead of Adapter? Tried putting my PostsAdapter there and using getRef but didn't work..

Comment: And it's not onClick.. its on my  onBindViewHolder

Comment: I copied the `onClick` handler from the code you gave and added the line of code that is needed. The `adapter` in that line should be a reference to your adapter instance. Since that wasn't in the code you shared, I couldn't be more specific than this.

Comment: I understood where's my mistake.. I'm using ListAdapter instead of FirebaseAdapter... sadly idk how can I conver it all now, must be some hard work.. But thank you :)